# Getting errors using APNS PHP

Tags: php, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Here's the code I'm using

```
<?php
$deviceToken = 'my device key';  // not putting in for security

$payload['aps'] = array('alert' => 'This is the alert text', 'badge' => 1, 'sound' => 'default');
$payload = json_encode($payload);

$apnsHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
$apnsPort = 2195;
$apnsCert = 'apns-dev.pem';

$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);

$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

$apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);

socket_close($apns);
fclose($apns);
?>
```

and I get these errors

> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: Unable to set private key file `apns-dev.pem' in /home/bryan/sendpush.php on line 14
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: failed to create an SSL handle in /home/bryan/sendpush.php on line 14
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: Failed to enable crypto in /home/bryan/sendpush.php on line 14
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /home/bryan/sendpush.php on line 14
>
> Warning: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/bryan/sendpush.php on line 17
>
> Warning: socket_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/bryan/sendpush.php on line 19
>
> Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/bryan/sendpush.php on line 20

I actually now got it down to these errors

> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure in /home/bryan/PushService.php on line 27
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: Failed to enable crypto in /home/bryan/PushService.php on line 27
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /home/bryan/PushService.php on line

Comment: kindly refer my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769189/streamsocketclient-error-in-php/1990439#1990439 it is how I solved the issue. HIH

Answer (score 3):

1. Use the absolute path for the private key instead of relative path.
2. Make sure the php user (or webserver user, depending.. `www-data`, `apache`, `nginx`, `www`...) is allowed to read it (`chown`, `chmod`).

Answer (score -3):

I was getting this error also. found out that I had set up the permission wrong on the folder that had the certificate file. This worked for me:

```
chmod 755 your_folder_that_has_certificate_files
```

Comment: I don't see how the certificate directory would benefit from having any write or execute certificates. Surely `444` (global read) would be enough?

Comment: Someone does not simply chmod 777/755 the whole server. It's a PRIVATE key for a reason.