# Pushnotification issue while sending from browser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ssl-certificate, apple-push-notifications

while i am using `push notification` in my application shows an error like below :

```
APNCRON: Started at 2012-02-08 00:32:42
3904

Warning:  stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14094415:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert certificate expired in /var/www/vhosts/solecollector.com/httpdocs/nikeadmin/apn_cron.php on line 75

Warning:  stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: Failed to enable crypto in /var/www/vhosts/solecollector.com/httpdocs/nikeadmin/apn_cron.php on line 75

Warning:  stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /var/www/vhosts/solecollector.com/httpdocs/nikeadmin/apn_cron.php on line 75

[1] Initiating push for UDID:a7fa910aef49a17bbd59ccf5c4487d9856b5b36e DevToken:20e05c55435094c84d27b2f5b9c217b5924fcb91e582388cc5fe9c9231d15c11 MSG:{"aps":{"badge":6,"sound":"default"}}

Warning:  fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /var/www/vhosts/solecollector.com/httpdocs/nikeadmin/apn_cron.php on line 118

[2] Initiating push for UDID:828ee672c35c99fe8c106ddd2439495aed2fff00 DevToken:b6eb618c8bee91f19561be8b3554823822036d121faac2f7a0d5cc1362c31e96 MSG:{"aps":{"badge":6,"sound":"default"}}

Warning:  fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /var/www/vhosts/solecollector.com/httpdocs/nikeadmin/apn_cron.php on line 118

close and reconnect the Apple server with 5 sec delay at 100

Warning:  stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14094415:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert certificate expired in /var/www/vhosts/solecollector.com/httpdocs/nikeadmin/apn_cron.php on line 91

Warning:  stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: Failed to enable crypto in /var/www/vhosts/solecollector.com/httpdocs/nikeadmin/apn_cron.php on line 91

Warning:  stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /var/www/vhosts/solecollector.com/httpdocs/nikeadmin/apn_cron.php on line 91
```

Error with `SSL`. Please help...

Comment: have you gone through the warning message. It explains the error itself..!!

Answer (score 0):

[APNS ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 connection fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372308/apns-ssl-gateway-sandbox-push-apple-com2195-connection-fails)
Chances are you don't have your .pem configured correctly, or at all.