# php SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Tags: php, macos, curl, openssl

I'm running PHP Version 5.6 as part of XAMPP in MacOSx El Capitan and having error on few `https` sites. e.g: `https://www.google.com/`

`file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed`

But no SSL error returned on these sites:

1. [GitHub](https://github.com)
2. [Composer](https://getcomposer.org)
3. [PayPal TLS Test](https://tlstest.paypal.com/)

Please find the list first what i've tried so far but nothing works.

**Tried Google first:**

1. [SSL error SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32211301/ssl-error-ssl3-get-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed)
2. [PHP - SSL certificate error: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858351/php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)
3. [HTTPS and SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed, CA is OK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400300/https-and-ssl3-get-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed-ca-is-ok)

## Manual

**1. Updated cert.pem file**

`php -r 'print_r(openssl_get_cert_locations());'`

and result was.

```
Array
(
    [default_cert_file] => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/openssl/cert.pem
    [default_cert_file_env] => SSL_CERT_FILE
    [default_cert_dir] => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/openssl/certs
    [default_cert_dir_env] => SSL_CERT_DIR
    [default_private_dir] => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/openssl/private
    [default_default_cert_area] => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/openssl
    [ini_cafile] => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/openssl/cert.pem
    [ini_capath] =>
)
```

Saved [this file cacert.pem](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) in `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/openssl/cert.pem`

Updated `php.ini` with following

```
openssl.cafile = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/openssl/cert.pem
curl.cainfo    = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/openssl/cert.pem
```

Restarted Apache but no succes. Tried to read pem file (no error returned)

```
echo file_get_contents("/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/openssl/cert.pem");
```

**Test Case**

It works fine on `github.com` `getcomposer.org` `paypal.com` but not on `google.com` (google.com works as well on my windows system)

```
php -r '$ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://tlstest.paypal.com/"); var_dump(curl_exec($ch)); var_dump(curl_error($ch));'
```

Result: `PayPal_Connection_OKbool(true)`

But on `google.com`

```
php -r '$ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/"); var_dump(curl_exec($ch)); var_dump(curl_error($ch));'
```

Result: `string(63) "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"`

**P.S:** Disabling peer verification won't be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, making sure that the correct cert.pem file exists was not sufficient. You need to also set your time zone in your php.ini to your actual time zone using the `date.timezone` key (in my case, I set it to America/Los Angeles). Otherwise, PHP will default to using UTC and your system clock will appear to be off. This solved the issue for me on Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11.2).