# Send email using XAMPP and codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, ssl

> fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate
>   verify failed
>
> fsockopen(): Failed to enable crypto
>
> fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Unknown
>   error)

-
Above are the errors that show up whenever I try to send an email.

I am using XAMPP and codeigniter

I only have windows defender and SmadAv (included this because other say its because of their anti-virus that is why they cannot send the email)

I already enabled `extension=php_openssl.dll` in the  `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`

Please Help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GMail fsockopen(): SSL operation failed error with Codeigniter and XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570064/gmail-fsockopen-ssl-operation-failed-error-with-codeigniter-and-xampp)

Comment: This is not a duplicate because the question you mentioned was solved by adjusting settings of AVAST. but as I mentioned I do not have avast

Comment: even if you are not using avast but port  465 is blocked  for sending an email

Comment: Deep can smadav be responsible for blocking 465?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/q/32211301/3898339 for OpenSSL Error messages:

Comment: but doesn't the solution make the system less secured?

Comment: I am talking about `openssl.cafile = "/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem"`

Comment: I followed your advice and downloaded the cacert.pem any instructions on where I should put it and how I would use it?

Comment: check this tutorial https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/196/xampp-wampp-php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate