# APNs push notification with macOS Sierra

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, apns-php, macos-sierra

I'm trying to send my phone a push notification using the simple PHP tool which connects to `ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195`, but the connection fails with the following errors:

```
Warning: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in <Users/.../file.php> on line 30

Warning: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in <Users/.../file.php> on line 30

Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in <Users/.../file.php> on line 30
Failed to connect: 0
```

This all started since I upgraded to the GM Seed of macOS Sierra.
What's new in macOS Sierra that affects SSL connections?
How do I resolve this?

Comment: Firstly you try to check Push notification works using some APNS Tester if you get notification then all Ok if not then you have to check from both side. You can test using this site http://pushtry.com/

Comment: The exact same folder (which has the certificate etc) works fine in OS X Mavericks but not in macOS Sierra. I think basically the issue is with locating the path of the certificate (`.pem`) file. I tried providing the absolute path as well as the relative path, and neither try worked.

Comment: Have u try to using this site?

Comment: That's really besides the point. I just want to get the bottom of why the php connection is failing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got same error, and this is what I did:

1) updated my openssl **(i think u dont need this) got to step 2, cause this will take about 10 minutes**

```
brew install openssl
```

make sure u updated it correct:

```
openssl version
```

If not, try this or google:

```
brew link --force openssl
```

2) check you php default_cert_file path:

```
php -r "print_r(openssl_get_cert_locations());"
```

this is what i got:

```
Array
(
[default_cert_file] => /usr/local/libressl/etc/ssl/cert.pem
[default_cert_file_env] => SSL_CERT_FILE
[default_cert_dir] => /usr/local/libressl/etc/ssl/certs
[default_cert_dir_env] => SSL_CERT_DIR
[default_private_dir] => /usr/local/libressl/etc/ssl/private
[default_default_cert_area] => /usr/local/libressl/etc/ssl
[ini_cafile] => 
[ini_capath] => 
)
```

3) download cacert.pem from here:

```
wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
```

4) move cacert.pem file to your default_cert_file path (as root):

```
sudo mv cacert.pem /usr/local/libressl/etc/ssl/cert.pem
```

**probably i'll need to create this directory first**

After this, my php script worked.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a TONNE!

Comment: Thanks. Saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks for the quick directions!

Answer (score 12):

I got the same error after upgrading to macOS Sierra while using  **[php script to send push notifications](https://github.com/jPaolantonio/SimplePush)**.

Solution with installing certificate to

`[default_cert_file] => /usr/local/libressl/etc/ssl/cert.pem` didn't help as well.

---

**Updated to PHP v. 5.6.27, macOS Sierra 10.12.4**

---

And after all, I found my problem. It was in the fact, that **macOS Sierra updated PHP version to 5.6.27**

To check it, type in Terminal

`php -v`

```
PHP 5.6.27 (cli) (built: Oct 23 2016 11:47:58) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

And here is [OpenSSL changes in PHP 5.6.x](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php)

As the brief workaround, someone suggested disabling brand-new security features in the php script (in the link above, very bottom part).

**Safer (and I recommend it)** would be a way to setup path to [entrust_2048_ca.cer](https://www.entrust.com/root-certificates/entrust_2048_ca.cer) explicitly like

```
 $streamContext = stream_context_create([
            'ssl' => [
                'verify_peer'      => true,
                'verify_peer_name' => true,
                'cafile'           => '/path/to/bundle/entrust_2048_ca.cer',
            ]
        ]);
```

It works as well .

Comment: I'm not sure if  **'verify_peer' => false** is secure decision, second one is good, thanks!

Comment: thanks bro, you saved my life ..
p.s : macsiera ... that too bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can get certificate from Entrust. Download the entrust_2048_ca.cer certificate from: https://www.entrust.com/get-support/ssl-certificate-support/root-certificate-downloads/. After downloading **entrust_2048_ca.cer**, I copied it in the same directory where my php script was and it all worked.

More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28222783/4253579

Answer (score 0):

adding to the answer given by @Sandar you can also set the cafile like this

```
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'cafile', '/path/to/entrust_2048_ca.cer');
```