# Is it possible to display an image inside the title text in an iOS Push Notification?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have a request from a client to implement this small image for certain cases of push notifications. The problem is the location must be in/beside the title (see attached image, the red-outlined box), and was just wondering if this is at all possible to do, and if so, how.

[image]

Comment: The answer is yes, a PushNotification acts like a viewcontroller and is configurable. Here is a full tutorial on how to subclass it : https://medium.com/@lucasgoesvalle/custom-push-notification-with-image-and-interactions-on-ios-swift-4-ffdbde1f457

Comment: @Olympiloutre This tutorial only shows the full customization of the *detail view*, since modifying the main layout is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No,** it's not possible to include images in notifications like that. You must include them as **media attachments** (which will appear at the right side of the notification), more information about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39822373/how-can-i-add-media-attachments-to-my-push-notifications-in-an-ios-10-app).

Alternatively, you can use an **emoji** in the title of the notification.