# Debug UNNotificationServiceExtension without remote notifications

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, ios10

I am creating an `UNNotificationServiceExtension`, but I'd like to test it without having actual remote notifications while developing it.

Is it possible to trigger it without remote notifications?

I have tried with `UNNotificationRequest`, but that does not seem to work for the service extension. I have tested with `UNNotificationContentExtension` and that works, but it doesn't seem to work on `UNNotificationServiceExtension`.

Answer (score 2):

Download Pusher binary for mac.
https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher

It is cools. Give it keychain access, it picks the push certificates, just type in the payload and device token and environment and done.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can with Local Notifications, but without a server, you can use the script from this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial modified with the answer from this question: [Push Notification in PHP using PEM file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221224/push-notification-in-php-using-pem-file) and send your own push notifications.  You'll have to modify the content in the script to include the mutable-content flag to trigger the extension.