# Connecting to Apple's APNS using cURL with HTTP\2 support via nghttp2

Tags: linux, curl, docker, apple-push-notifications, nghttp2

I've attempted to compile cURL with HTTP/2 support by following [this tutorial](https://serversforhackers.com/video/curl-with-http2-support). I'm using [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) and my application is based off the [official PHP Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/), which uses Debian, although I've produced the same problems in an Ubuntu machine running inside a [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) VM.

There appears to be no problem at first. Indeed, running `curl --version` shows everything I'd expect:

```
curl 7.47.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.1 OpenSSL/1.0.1k zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.29 libssh2/1.4.3 nghttp2/1.7.1 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets
```

Also, I can connect to https://nghttp2.org just fine:

```
curl --http2 -I https://nghttp2.org
HTTP/2.0 200
date:Mon, 15 Feb 2016 18:02:34 GMT
content-type:text/html
content-length:6680
last-modified:Thu, 11 Feb 2016 14:29:49 GMT
etag:"56bc9add-1a18"
link:</stylesheets/screen.css>; rel=preload; as=stylesheet
accept-ranges:bytes
x-backend-header-rtt:0.000581
server:nghttpx nghttp2/1.8.0-DEV
via:1.1 nghttpx
strict-transport-security:max-age=31536000
x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection:1; mode=block
x-content-type-options:nosniff
```

The problems begin when trying to connect to Apple's recently re-launched [APNS Provider API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/APNsProviderAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW1) which now runs on HTTP/2.

I've installed curl via Homebrew on my Mac (using `--with-nghttp2`) and I can get the following (expected) response:

```
curl -d 'Hello' --http2 https://api.push.apple.com/3/device/test
{"reason":"Forbidden"}
```

However, if I try to run the same command from within my Docker image, I get:

```
curl -d 'Hello' --http2 https://api.push.apple.com/3/device/test
?@@?HTTP/2 client preface string missing or corrupt. Hex dump for received bytes: 504f5354202f332f6465766963652f746573742048545450
```

I'm unsure why this problems seems to be specific to Apple's service, and what needs to be done to remedy the situation.

Any help would be *greatly* appreciated!

Comment: This Q may be more appropriate on the related site http://apple.stackexchange.com (AskDifferently). Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it there. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone seeing this in the future, I ended up solving this, and the answer is on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/757553/updated-curl-not-taking-effect-in-php/761819#761819).

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is, that OpenSSL/1.0.1k doesn't come with ALPN protocol.

Apple requires it, whereas https://nghttp2.org is happy with NPN.

So to solve this, get OpenSSL/1.0.2 to work and you are all set.