# How to update PHP curl extension in Linux/Mac?

Tags: php, curl, xampp, lamp

What is the easiest way to update the curl extension in PHP? I installed XAMPP on Mac/Linux and noticed that it doesn't allow me to use HTTP2, so I thought of compiling my own curl with the `--with-nghttp2` option, but how can I include this into PHP? Installing curl with

```
brew install curl --with-nghttp2
```

on Mac doesn't change anything in the phpInfo(), the curl version used by PHP remains the same as before.

Comment: I ended up switching from PHP to NodeJS, among the reasons is that it's much easier to debug and curl works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

The reasons your phpinfo() doesn't update is because XAMPP's CURL and your terminal default CURL are two different CURLs. homebrew installs/updates your system default curl but not your XAMPP's curl.

you can type `which curl` in your terminal to check where your system default CURL is located.

Type `brew reinstall curl --with-openssl --with-nghttp2` in your terminal to reinstall your curl with openssl and nghttp2. brew is nice because it helps settle the openssl and nghttp2 dependencies.

I didn't dig into it but copying this curl to the xampp library folder and replacing the CURL did not work. what worked was recompiled CURL https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html the prefix is your xampp library folder. point your --with-openssl=[homebrew cellar openssl folder] and --with-nghttp2=[homebrew cellar nghttp2 folder]

sorry for the vague answer but if you get the general concept it shouldn't be too hard to figure out the detailed steps.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help! I immediately tried your suggestion and I was confident that it would work, but unfortunately after manually compiling curl the Apache Web Server in the XAMPP control panel doesn't start anymore. Do you have any idea what the problem could be? I have XAMPP 5.6.21.

Comment: you need to check the logs on what's the error as to why it doesn't start anymore. all compiling does is replace the curl and curl-config file in the library folder.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no error log, but I tried backing up the `libcurl.*` files in the xamppfiles/lib folder before running `make install` and replacing the ones generated by the install command, and now Apache starts. Did you use a special flag to tell the compiler not to replace those files? Now the problem is that in the control panel, the used curl version is still `7.45.0`, but I compiled version `7.49.1`. Is there anything else I have to change?

Comment: Can you please tell me the steps you did in order to update curl?

Comment: sorry i don't have the steps, but that's really all i did. i downloaded curl and compiled it using the brew libraries and using the following flags --prefix=[the-xampp-library-folder] --with-nghttp2=[brew-nghttp2-folder] --with-ssl=[brew-openssl-folder] and then restart the server.