# APNS notification using API is not working

Tags: php, curl, apple-push-notifications

I tried executing the API APNS using CURL . The code is as below

```
$pem_file       =  'public/assets/pem/test.pem';
$pem_secret     = '';
$apns_topic     = 'com.test.demo';
if(defined('CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0'))
{
   $devicetoken=['54688ae0e1ecc3bc0d517521f4935c014342ecca792ef798f0e63652a4620ed4','de963dfbc03f5de416c7d806e04a6f3276716f246942fa2a61cffa393a780120','a08832de8b72567aa487beefe50e4e29caaa4a51ab14706fc8f0ef9df1f6b9c4','48335901c12bf02a03cef453d2e7739eaac9779991cafef3fa70ffe587ea3f12'];

$sample_alert = '{"aps":{"alert":"hi","sound":"default"}}';
   foreach($devicetoken as $device_token)
   {
    $url = "https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/$device_token";

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sample_alert);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("apns-topic: $apns_topic"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $pem_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $pem_secret);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

//On successful response you should get true in the response and a status code of 200
     var_dump($response);echo "----";var_dump($httpcode);
    }
}
else{
   echo"NOt a supported version";
}
```

Iam getting the result as :

```
  �@@uUnexpected HTTP/1.x request: POST /3/device/54688ae0e1ecc3bc0d517521f4935c014342ecca792ef798f0e63652a4620ed4 bool(true) ----int(0)
```

I was trying this method to handle the invalid device token .Earlier i tried ssl using PHP like this link(http://learn-php-by-example.blogspot.in/2013/01/working-with-apple-push-notification.html) , In that when a invalid device token is in the db and when we pass it through the loop the push notification stops working . So i was trying the API method .

Thanks in advance for your response guys

Comment: don't put original credentials here

Comment: the response seems to indicate they received this in HTTP1.x ! not as per your settings. Check your `php curl` installation ?

Comment: did you try a verbose curl ? I sometimes get lots more insight into apparent `peer` issues that way.

Answer (score 1):

for the new HTTP/2 APNS provider API, you can use curl to send push notifications : [New APNS Provider API and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684099/new-apns-provider-api-and-php)

Comment: I tried that link only , check the code i posted .Earlier i was using ssl that too i followed from a link mentioned .

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that your cURL version supports HTTP/2 (you'll have to compile cURL with this, it isn't active by default).

Then make sure cURL is using OpenSSL v1.0.2 or above.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly enable your `http2` in curl package of your php.

Also see the `phpinfo()` if you have already enabled the http2 support for curl or not.

After that just set your `CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION` curl option with 3

[image]