# Cannot connect to APNS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I just got this problem where I can't connect to APNS. Never experienced this before.
Every time use try to connect with telnet like so,

telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195

I get a timeout or it just keeps trying to connect. I normally use telnet to check if i can connect to APNS. Today is the first time I'm experiencing trouble. Is there something wrong with the apple servers maybe at this moment. Any kind of info on why this might be happening now is most appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372308/apns-ssl-gateway-sandbox-push-apple-com2195-connection-fails

Comment: I'm not getting connected at this moment. Thats the problem.

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but I'm having problem integrating APNS into my django code can you please share your code for sending push notification - and does it support tls?

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, solved it.. the network guy at my company had the 2195 port blocked. Thanks for everyones time.