# PHP fails socket connection with Apple notification gateway

Tags: php, iphone, sockets, ssl, apple-push-notifications

Disclaimer: **on SO I found many similar questions and some answers but none solved my issue**.

I have this easy PHP code:

```
<?php
    $deviceToken = "myDeviceToken";
    $message = "Hello from server";
    $badge = 1;
    $sound = "default";

    // Construct the notification payload
    $body['aps'] = array(
        'alert' => $message
    );

    if ($badge) {
        $body['aps']['badge'] = $badge;
    }

    if ($sound) {
        $body['aps']['sound'] = $sound;
    }

    /* End of Configurable Items */
    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'my.pem');

    $fp = stream_socket_client("ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195", $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);

    if (!$fp) {
        print "Failed to connect $err $errstrn";
        return;
    } else {
        print "Connection OK\n";
    }

    $payload = json_encode($body);
    $msg = chr(0) . pack("n", 32) . pack("H*", str_replace(" ", "", $deviceToken)) . pack("n", strlen($payload)) . $payload;
    print "sending message :" . $payload . "\n";
    fwrite($fp, $msg);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

**When called from browser I receive:**

> [13-Dec-2011 18:52:52] PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure in /home/srv/public_html/myTest.php on line 28
>
> [13-Dec-2011 18:52:52] PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: Failed to enable crypto in /home/srv/public_html/myTest.php on line 28
>
> [13-Dec-2011 18:52:52] PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /home/srv/public_html/myTest.php on line 28

Any idea of what's going on?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453015/ios-push-notification-problem-when-using-crontab-scheduler
  
this link was the answer for the above issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some random finding from the internet which could help:

1. It may be a certificate problem. Try the stream options `allow_self_signed` and `verify_peer` to check that.
2. Try to use explicitely `sslv2://` or `sslv3://` ?
3. Permission problem on "/dev/urandom"

Comment: it was a certificate problem, but far more stupid than the one solved by your point 1. The developer who produced the certificate inserted an unrequested password, without either mentioning he did. Thanks for the quality pointers.

Comment: this morning out of nowhere, we started to receive 'SSL operation failed with code 1' from our servers. Defining the ssl version for the APN server solved the problem. sslv3://... I think apple made a few changes on their servers.

Comment: Can you please give a complete php statement for your first point. I am mobile developer and does not know much of php. Also please explain your 3rd point. What is "dev/urandom"?

Comment: You can read the related PHP documentation here: http://php.net/manual/context.ssl.php
Example included here: http://php.net/manual/function.stream-context-create.php

Comment: Ask Developer to export certificate and key differently from keychain access. If they export both in one go this error will arise.