# Amazon EC2 PHP & Apple push notification Failed

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, apple-push-notifications

Thanks for reading my question.
I'm trying to send push notification from PHP (installed on Amazon EC2), code works on localhost but when move to EC2, it give error:

`PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure in ... on line 24, referer: ...
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in ... on line 24, referer: ...
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in ... on line 24, referer: ...`

Path to pem file is correct (I tried absolute path).
Thanks for help!

Comment: Could you share the relevant parts of your code?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8501114/592139) suggests that using `sslv3://` instead of `ssl://` may help.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection to apple servers are currently dropped from the ec2 default firewall (the default profile only allows ports 22 and 80 if I remember correctly).
You have to allow ports 2195-2196 at your ec2 security group.

Comment: Security groups are for inbound connections so this is not needed.