# push notification in ios

Tags: php, ios, push-notification

I am new in a php and write a code for push notification in codeigniter but I got these erros.

Here is my model..

```
function sendmessage($appid, $deviceid, $status, $message)
{

    $deviceToken = '0f744707bebcf74f9b7c25d48e3358945f6aa01da5ddb387462c7eaf61bbad78';

    $message = 'My first push notification!';

    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
    //stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'essar@123');

    $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);

    if (!$fp){
        exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
              }
          else {
          print "Connection OK/n";
               }
    echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

    $body['aps'] = array(
        'alert' => $message,
        'sound' => 'default'
        );
    $payload = json_encode($body);
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

    if (!$result)
        echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
    else
        echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;
    fclose($fp);

    $data = array(
    'message' => $this->message . 'add',
    'appid' => $this->appid,
    'deviceid' => $this->deviceid,
    'status' => $status
            );
    $this->sendmessage($data);
```

Error message:

> Message: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure Message: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto Message: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error)

Comment: have you read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453015/ios-push-notification-problem-when-using-crontab-scheduler - basically, make sure you're using the correct path to your `ck.pem` file.

Comment: make sure your server is able to reach the sandbox server on the 2195 port

Answer (score 5):

Once you created the provisional certificates and push notification for both development and distribution. Follow the steps for Generate **Push Notification**

In order to use the certificates you generated, you need to create a **PEM file** that stores both, your Apple Push Notification Service SSL Certificate and your Private Key. You can create the PEM file from a terminal.

Navigate to the directory that contains the certificates and key you generated earlier and execute the following steps. The file names here reflect the names of the certificates that were generated as part of this lesson. You have to update the syntax according the names you gave your certificates.

First create the application certificate PEM file. You can do this by double clicking on the aps_developer_identity.cer certificate file, then opening the Keychain Assistant and exporting the certificate as ap12 file and then converting it to a PEM file, in the same fashion as the PushNotificationApp.p12 is converted to a PEM file. Alternatively you can use a single command line that converts the aps_developer_identity.cer certificate file directly to a PEM file. Here we are opting for the single command line option, as follows:

```
openssl x509 -inform der -outform pem -in aps_developer_identity.cer -out PushNotificationAppCertificate.pem
```

Now create the application key PEM file as follows. You need to enter the import password and PEM pass phrase:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in PushNotificationApp.p12 -out PushNotificationAppKey.pem -nocerts
```

Enter Import Password:
MAC verified OK
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:

Now concatenate the two files:

```
cat PushNotificationAppCertificate.pem PushNotificationAppKey.pem > PushNotificationAppCertificateKey.pem
```

Open a Mac terminal and execute the following line from the directory that contains the certificates you generated:

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert PushNotificationAppCertificate.pem -key PushNotificationAppKey.pem
```

You are then asked to enter the pass phrase for the key you submitted:

```
Enter pass phrase for PushNotificationAppKey.pem:
```

If everything worked, then the server should send you a lot of information that may look something like the following:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)

depth=1 /C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate verify return:0
...
Key-Arg : None

Start Time: 1326899631 Timeout : 300 (sec) Verify return code: 0 (ok)
At the end of this, you can enter some text and then select the return key. We entered the text "**Hello World**".

**Hello World

closed**
```

This completes the communication with the server and verifies that our certificates work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have been having the same issue as you mentioned here. This took some time and head scratching to find...

The solution that I found that corrected the handshake error was to download the [entrust](https://www.entrust.net/downloads/binary/entrust_2048_ca.cer) certificate, and include this in the stream context using the code below:

```
$entrustCert =  '<full path to cert>/entrust_2048_ca.cer';
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'cafile', entrustCert);
```

There does seem to intermittent connection issues with the sandbox APN service. I occasionally get errors returned like:

```
Warning: stream_socket_client(): SSL: Connection reset by peer 
Warning: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto
```

I hope this is a time saver for someone!

Answer (score 0):

```
function send_iOS_notifications($device_tokens, $notification_content)
    {
        $this->load->library('apn');
        $this->apn->payloadMethod = 'enhance'; // you can turn on this method for debuggin purpose
        $this->apn->connectToPush();

                //$badge_count = $this->set_and_get_ios_active_notifications('',$device_token);

        // adding custom variables to the notification
        $this->apn->setData($notification_content);

                $message = $notification_content['message'];
                if ((strpos($message, 'http://') !== false) || (strpos($message, 'https://') !== false)) {
                    $message = "Image";
                }

        //$send_result = $this->apn->sendMessage($device_token, 'Test notif #1 (TIME:'.date('H:i:s').')', /*badge*/ 2, /*sound*/ 'default'  );
        $send_result = $this->apn->sendMessage($device_tokens, $message, /*badge*/ '', /*sound*/ 'default'  );


        if($send_result){
            log_message('debug','Sending successful');
            $result['status'] = true;
            $result['message'] = 'Sending successful';
        }
        else{
            log_message('error',$this->apn->error);
            $result['status'] = true;
            $result['message'] = $this->apn->error;
        }
        $this->apn->disconnectPush();


    }
```