# Track push notification ios

Tags: ios, notifications, push, tracking

It's possible to track my app push notification in iOS?.

Something like google analytics for push notification.
I want to know the users who receive the notifications and the users who have disabled my app push notification. It's possible?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156873/push-notification-in-ios/39368761#39368761