# how to retrieve ck.pem file for push notifications php

Tags: php, ssl, cron, apple-push-notifications

Hi I'm having trouble sending push notifications from a cron job invoked php script. However the same script works when I invoke the script from the terminal so I know its a problem retrieving the ck.pem. When I hit the script from the terminal I just use the lines

```
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
```

to get the ck.pem and it works because the ck.pem file is right on my desktop and local. When I hit the script thats invoked by the cron job it does not have the ck.pem file locally so I uploaded the ck.pem file to the server so the php script invoked from the cron job could access it and this is the code I use to retrieve it

```
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', file_get_contents("http://www.website.com/Certificates/ck.pem"));
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
```

however I get the errors

> PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto
>
> PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to
>   ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error)
>
> PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code
>   1. OpenSSL Error messages:

and all these errors happen on the third line of code in the following segment:

```
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
```

So like I said Im pretty sure its because of the ck.pem file and I made sure that ports 2195 and 2196 are open so it is not that and I can't figure this out. Any help or suggestions would be greatly greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Solved this answer with this stack overflow link: [iOS push notification does not work when using crontab scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453015/ios-push-notification-problem-when-using-crontab-scheduler)

I was retrieving the ck.pem file the wrong way