# CENTOS - blocked ports issue

Tags: linux, centos, port, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to establish a connection to Apple Push Notification Service through a remote machine which runs CENTOS. Unfortunately it seems that the related ports, 2195, 2196 are somewhat blocked.

When I telnet from my local osx it seems to work fine:

```
$ telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195

Trying 17.149.34.66...
Connected to gateway.sandbox.push-apple.com.akadns.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

However when I telnet from my remote server it gives a timeout error.

So far, I tried to disable the iptables but it hasn't worked.

```
[root@centos01 ~]# service iptables save
[root@centos01 ~]# service iptables stop
```

Is there any other component that can block my connection to remote machines on certain ports ?

Thanks,
Hadar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stream\_socket\_client unable to connect (connection timed out)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769189/stream-socket-client-unable-to-connect-connection-timed-out)

Answer (score 3):

CentOS usually has many strict rules in the IP-tables. Try adding rules to allow access to the ports in your server.
The idea to 'STOP' the IP-tables on the server is not a good idea at all.

Also CentOS implements SE-Linux that is basically an advanced security enhancement. It is possible that the SE-Linux module is blocking requests.

You may refer to this : http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux

Just to test whether your problem is caused by the SE Module, you may want to temporarily disable it's enforcement by doing:

```
    $ echo 0> /selinux/enforce
```

Make sure you re enable enforcement after the testing.

```
    $ echo 1> /selinux/enforce
```

Comment: It's been a while now. You should "Accept" (green tick) an answer when something works. It will help others searching for the same problem on the internet.